# typealias in class vs in function in swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, performance, swift

1. What's the difference between a typealias declaration in class vs its declaration inside a function?
2. Is there any performance detail?
3. Is it a good idea to use them inside functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The difference is just the scope. A declaration inside a function hides one from outside.
2. Since this is handled all by the compiler it has nothing to do with performance.
3. Use it, where it makes sense (from a scope view)